# Spy on destructured require method

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, require, sinon

I have a method where I import a method with destructuring.  I am trying to spy on this method but keep running into errors.

```
const { addition } = require('./my-math-lib');

const additionSpy = sinon.spy(addition);

testMethod.doMath();

expect(additionSpy.calledOnce).to.be.equal(true);
```

Unfortunately this unit test does not work.  Whey I look at the additionSpy object, I see the notCalled is true.

If I change the code to -

```
const mathStuff = require('./my-math-lib');

const additionSpy = sinon.spy(mathStuff, 'addition');

testMethod.doMath();

expect(additionSpy.calledOnce).to.be.equal(true);
```

This unit test will pass.

Answer (score 3):

Sinon's spy method can't modify functions. Functions aren't mutable in Javascript. Sinon's spy method can create a new function (`additionSpy` in your first example), or it can modify an object and replace a method on it (your second example). Your second example looks correct for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks and the second example works.  I just really wanted to use destructuring in my require calls.